# Reverse a boolean of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, boolean, observablecollection, reverse

I just aim to reverse a boolean of my ObservableCollection called ActiviteCollection.

This boolean is automaticaly defined to be False (0) but when I click on a button, some booleans become true. It's this reverse I don't succeed to perform and I have found nothing like this on the web.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I can Edit my post if you want some code, but a general way of reversing a boolean of an ObservableCollection should be enough help me to find what I aim.

This is the script for the Button which will reverse the Boolean:

```
private void click_PrisEnCompte(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (ViewModel)(sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem).DataContext;

    foreach (var data in DonneesBrutes.SelectedItems)
    {
        if(viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTMActivite == DonneesBrutes.CurrentItem.ToString()))
        {
            var reversedCollection = viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Select(t => !t);
        }
    }
}
```

This script currently doesn't work, got error on the Select: `The type Arguments for method ... cannot be inferred for the usage.` and on !t `Cannot apply Operator ! to operand of type.....`

Comment: If you want to "reverse" a boolean then just negate it. `var a = true;` `a=!a;`

Comment: Select(t => !t) compiles for me ... What is ActiveCollection? Also, it looks like your using MVVM ... why do you have what i assume is a click event in code behind? look at Commands.

Comment: I indeed use MVVM pattern. ActiveCollection is my ObservableCollection `public ObservableCollection<Activite> ActiviteCollection { get; set; } `  `ActiviteCollection = new ObservableCollection<Activite>(_BDDInterneEntities.Activite);`

Comment: looks to me that ActiviteCollection is not a ObservableCollection<bool>...

Comment: I don't think too. It's an ObservableCollection of `public partial class Activite
    {
        public string PMRQTOTMActivite { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Flag { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: you OC is not of type bool. your class 'Activite' may contain a boolean, but your error is due to Class Activite not having a ! operator.

Comment: exactly but everyone has assumed you were talking about an ObservableCollection<bool>

Comment: try somthing like ActiviteCollection.Foreach(a => { a.Flag = !a.Flag; });

Comment: @AlexAnderson Cannot resolve symbol 'Foreach' Am I missing something? `if(viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Any(c => c.PMRQTOTMActivite == DonneesBrutes.CurrentItem.ToString()))
                {
                    viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Foreach(a => a.Flag = !a.Flag);
                }`

Comment: Kraenys - learn to use tools avalaible to you, the linq extention is ForEach ... a quick google would show that i made a type. Start solving your own problems instead of relying on others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var data in DonneesBrutes.SelectedItems)
{
    foreach (var item in viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Where(c => c.PMRQTOTMActivite == DonneesBrutes.CurrentItem.ToString()))
    {
        item.MyBoolean = !item.MyBoolean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay sounds correct. That was what I looked for. Cost me expensive cause it seems I wasn't enough precise or clear, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b = false;
b = !b; //Inverted!!
```

in an Observable Collection

```
ObservableCollection<Bool> BooleanList;
foreach(bool b in BooleanList)
    b = !b;
```

Comment: might want to try and compile this

Comment: oops, forgot you cant edit during an enumeration. But it was intended as more pseudo code than acctual code.

Comment: * iteration not enumeration ... god i need lunch.

Answer (score 0):

The following will "reverse" every item in your collection:

`var reversedCollection = from t in ActiviteCollection select !t;`

Comment: If I'm doing this: `var reversedCollection = viewModel.ActiviteCollection.Select(t => !t);` which is the LinQ way, I have error on the Select. I'll edit my question with my buttonClickEvent

Comment: Not sure exactly the cause, but a workaround is specifying the type explicitly like this: `var reversedCollection = from bool t in ActiviteCollection select !t;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "reverse" the boolean at a given index can do this:

```
ActiviteCollection[index] = !ActiviteCollection[index];
```

Comment: What do you mean by Index? The boolean I want to reverse? If it is, I have an error when I adapt your code: `viewModel.ActiviteCollection[Flag] = !viewModel.ActiviteCollection[Flag];`, Cannot resolve symbol Flag. Flag is the boolean I want to reverse

Comment: you need to know which index in the collection the boolean was taken from. Ie you need to know it's the 2nd boolean in the collection for example, in which case you use ActiviteCollection[1] = !ActiviteCollection[1];

Comment: nevermind. I assumed ActiviteCollection was ObservableCollection<bool>.